What can I do when the bank has deposited my paycheck into someone else’s account and refuses to pay me?
I signed up for direct deposit with cash app to have my paycheck deposited in the account they gave me on the direct deposit form that I signed and gave to my employer per cash app’s instructions.
However when my employer sent my paycheck it somehow went to someone else’s account. According to cash app my employer sent my paycheck to the wrong account, but after doing extensive research and tracing back to the originating bank, the account matched the account on the direct deposit form that I was given.
I have filed several complaints with CFPB, FDIC, FTC, OCC, NCDA, Texas Department of Banking just to name a few yet I still haven’t received my paycheck and cash app has acknowledged that they have it but says it went to an account not in my name.
The originating bank has done 2 recalls on the funds but they both came back rejected due to funds not not available. Cash App suggest I have the originating bank send Sutton Bank a letter of indemnification however they refuse to do it.
What else can I do in this situation? I feel that cash app has stolen my paycheck but wouldn’t it be the fault of Sutton Bank for even releasing my paycheck to an account that wasn’t in my name? Is it even possible for my paycheck to have even made to cash app at all if my name were not even on the account? Isn’t this grounds for a lawsuit? Who would be at fault, Sutton Bank or Cash App?

@keshlam, I did go to my employer and they have tried to work with Cash App by having their bank (the originating bank do a recall on the funds (twice) however they both were rejected due to the funds not available. It clearly shows on the rejection response that you get back the account number and it’s the exact account number on the direct deposit form that Cash App gave me. So therefore it’s not my employer it’s Cash App/ Sutton Bank problem or whoever is responsible for issuing the account numbers. The money made it to Sutton Bank just not to me. Maybe they issued me someone else’s acct #?

Cash App really shouldn't be involved,; this should be a bank to bank transfer. (Unless Cash App is your bank, which would strike me as foolhardy .) Cash App's docs say their support can be reached at 1 866-992-9838; what do they say they're seeing on their end if the wire?

@keshlam, as I have stated in my question that I have asked about this, I have contacted cash app and they are envolved because according to Sutton Bank, Cash App informed them that they had located the account in question but it was not in my name. That seems impossible to me. How did it leave my employer’s bank, get to Sutton Bank and even to Cash App if my name isn’t on the account? They are clearly “gaslighting  me”! Does that make any sense to you??

No, it makes no sense to me. If it went to an account not in your name, fine; you need to figure out who f'd up the transaction and they need to correct it. It could be the bank, it could be your employer. It could be whatever Cash App is, it could be you. Find where the incorrect account number was introduced. That's assuming Cas App is legit; this is the only mention I've ever heard of them but I'm not going to do the research right now.

That's something you have to take up with your employer.
They need to talk to the bank, show their record of the transaction, show that they entered it correctly, and ask why it didn't go through.
If they didn't enter it correctly, that's their problem and they owe you the money. The fact that they accidentally paid somebody else is their problem, not yours. Unless you did something like giving them the wrong bank account information, in which case you will probably have to accept that that paycheck is gone, and you'll have to make sure it gets corrected before the next check.
Whoever made the mistake eats the cost. You need to ask your employer for help determining where the mistake was made.

It is also possible that the funds can be clawed back from the wrong account. Just because someone has received funds does not mean they are entitled to them if an honest mistake was made. My point is that "whoever made the mistake eats the cost" is not necessarily correct. But, of course, that's not up to @Kimberly to take up.

s/eats/is supposed to eat/ if you prefer. And if you get an unexpected deposit in your account you should expect that to be corrected and budget accordingly, and should probably ask the bank to investigate sooner rather than later to minimize your own inconvenience.

@Karl Sounds like they've tried the claw back but the money's not there.  They owe it but collecting it is another matter...
